# why are the eigenvalues of the normalized Laplacian matrix of graph $G$ non-negative?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple and connected graph with $n$ vertices. $d_i$ is the degree of the vertex $i$. Let $L$ be the Laplacian matrix of  $G$. $D$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with the elements of diagonal are $d_i$ $i=1,...,n$. The normalized Laplacian matrix of  $G$ defined to be $L_{norm}  =D^{-\frac12}L D^{-\frac12}$. So why are the eigenvalues of the normalized Laplacian matrix $L_{norm}$ of graph $G$ non-negative?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the minimum valency of $G$ is positve, and use $N$ for the normalized Laplacian. Suppose $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and set $y=D^{-1/2}x$. Then
\[
  x^TNx = y^TLy.
\]
Since $L$ is positive semidefinite, $y^TLy\ge0$ and it follows that $x^TNx\ge0$ for any vector $x$. Hence $N$ is positive semidefinite, and so its eigenvalues are non-negative. [The one-sentence summary of all this is that conjugate matrices have the same inertia.]

Comment: For the interested reader, you can go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix)  to see why $L$ is positive semidefinite.